# PHPMailer sending multiple times mail to same recipient

Tags: php, email

I am using PHP Mailer function to send mail. In order to send mail to multiple recipients, I am using for loop as per below :-

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($com_string_array);$i++)
 {
    $soc_memb_comm_info = explode(",",$com_string_array[$i]);
    $mailing->send_mail_with_attachment($soc_memb_comm_info[4],           
    $soc_memb_comm_info[3],$upload_path,$file_name,$message);
 }
   public function    
   send_mail_with_attachment($to,$full_name,$file_path,$file_name,$message)
{ 
 //Other configuration parameter of PHP Mailer.
 $this->AddAddress($to);    
 $this->Subject = "Welcome ";
 $this->Body    = $message;
 $this->AltBody = $email_msg;
 $this->AddAttachment($file_path,$file_name);
 if(!$this->Send())
 {
 echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $this->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
 }
```

My issue is that mail is going multipile times to same reciepient. For eg. if I am sending mail to three people then first person is getting mail three times. 
1. Directly to First Person.
2. Directly to First Person, second person.
3. Directly to First Person, Second Person and Third Person.

Kindy advises why such issue is coming.

Answer (score 3):

The mailer you use is not reset each time you use the function to send. So when you call the send function the second time, the first recipient is still there, as well as the first attachment. You did not mention the attachments but i guess in the second mail the attachment will be there twice.

Either you have to use a new instance of PHPMailer or you can clear all recipient and attachments before you send a mail.

```
$this->clearAllRecipients();
$this->clearAttachments();
```

Comment: Bingo this solves the problem. Thnx a lot for your support. Would like to rate up this ans. Dont know why Quest and Ans has 0 points.

Comment: Glad to help. 0 points because the 'new' section of php-tagged questions is quite an active place with many questions per minute. not every question gets the attention it deserves. just accepting the answer would help me a lot, thx :)